Reflective writing
I'm writing a personal reflection on moving to another country. Does the last sentence in this example make sense?
"Firstly, I would suggest begin preparations well in advance. Maybe in this process you need wait for your visa and find a comfortable accommodation place. These things are all spend time by yourself."
Thanks.

Writing advice is off-topic.

Short answer: No, I do not understand what you are saying in the final sentence.

General proofreading isn't covered here. There are several problems in the example, though, and no, the final sentence doesn't make sense, so I suggest getting general help from some other source.

"(to) spend time by yourself" is a phrase headed by the verb "spend".  But the clause structure "These things are ...." needs to be complemented by a noun or an adjective ("these things are chores" or "these things are difficult")
So the last sentence is ungrammatical.  It's not clear what you want to say.  I guess "these things" refers to the preparations like "waiting for a visa" and "finding accommodation".  You might say that they are "solitary activities" or they "were done alone". Or you should completely scrap the sentence and go with something like "I spent a lot of time by myself in the months before departing"

I tried to understand the whole paragraph. Is this what you mean?
First and foremost, I would suggest you should begin preparations well in advance. While you are waiting for your visa you can find a suitable accommodation. It is necessary to spend your time for all these."
